Apple appstoreconnect analytics API returns download data for only a few weeks ago
I have been sending requests to the Appstore Connect API for 3 types of reports; download data, discovery data, and install data.
The documentation notes that data is available as far back as Jan 1, 2024. I have found this to be true with install data reports. But the other two go back only about 5 weeks.
The process of getting these reports involves two HTTP requests, one to get segment instances with the report ID and one to get media links with the segment IDs. For dates just over 5 weeks ago, it returns segments but 404 for the request for medial links with those segments. For even later dates it doesn't return any segments.
I am using the 'granularity' and 'WEEKLY' param but I get the same results with other options.
I don't think it's an error with my code because I'm receiving data for earlier dates but not dates before 5 weeks ago.
I need some ideas to move forward because I need to backfill the data to at least April, 2024. Do you think Apple is just being inconsistent and I am f'd?
